# Sending content from my frontend to my PHP/MySQL-backend

Tags: php, mysql

When I send my content from my frontend it successfully reaches my if (!empty)-statement but the table in my phpmyadmin/mysql-database does not recieve the information and does not add it.

I have two tables. One varchar (text) named "photo" and a ID called "id" which is A_I.

With my current code I only send (well attempt to send) the text about "photo" but nothing about the ID as it is A_I? Maybe I need to add some addiotional code to that as well and that might be the issue here and the reason the database does not seem to add the content that I send?

```
<?php 

 $value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

 $mysql_pekare= new mysqli ("", "","", "");

   if(!empty($value)) {

      echo "You reached the IF-statement";
      $stmt = $mysql_pekare->prepare("INSERT INTO photoAlbum(`photo`) VALUES(?)");

      $stmt->bind_param("s", $value['photo']);

      $stmt->execute();

      $stmt->close();

      $mysql_pekare->close();
   }

?>
```

In my frontend when I send the content I recieve this in the log:

```
{"photo":"test"}
```

And I also recieve this in the log, the echo call I did if it reaches the IF function which it successfully does:

```
"You reached the IF-statement"
```

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param("ss", $value);` should only have 1 `s` not 2 -> `$stmt->bind_param("s", $value);`, as you only have 1 param `$value`

Comment: updated it. still does not reach the db however

Comment: Also, since you use `json_decode()`, you are expecting your `$value` to be an array, so you need to do `$value['photo']` in `$stmt->bind_param("s", $value['photo']);`

Comment: updated that one as well. still no result though. is it because the "id" is being ignored and not mentioned somewhere?

Comment: If `id` is `auto_increment` than you do not need to include it in the query, as MySQL will automatically create it on insertion. Have you verified that `$mysql_pekare` is a valid connection?

Comment: Have you also inspected `$value`, ie `print_r($value)` or `var_dump($value)` to verify what is there?

Comment: I get this in the log if I print_r it right after the insert into-code: `stdClass Object
(
    [photo] => test
)`

Comment: I have never heard of a stdClass before. "text" is the text i send in from my frontend btw

Comment: So `$value` is an object, not array, so try `$value->photo` -> `$stmt->bind_param("s", $value->photo);`

Comment: Hell yeah. Works! Make an answer and I will upvote it. Thanks alot Sean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns an object, so your value is in `$value->photo`.

So your `INSERT` code should be -

```
if(!empty($value)) {

  echo "You reached the IF-statement";
  $stmt = $mysql_pekare->prepare("INSERT INTO photoAlbum(`photo`) VALUES(?)");

  $stmt->bind_param("s", $value->photo);

  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();

  $mysql_pekare->close();
}
```

Comment: Works! if i want to add another object, then if i understand you correctly I will just need to add another "s" so: "ss", $value->photo, $value->photo2?

Comment: Yes, if you send `{"photo":"test", "photo2":"test2"}` then you would access the 2nd with `$value->photo2`

Answer (score 0):

you must put the value for mysqli constructor required like localhost or ip , username of database , password of your database and database name then it will work fine for Example:-

```
$mysql_pekare=new mysqli ("localhost", "username","password", "databasename");
```

Comment: I have that figured out. That is not the issue. Sean solved it now though!